# Perfect Number Method w/ Range

Tags: java, for-loop, range, perfect-numbers

I can't get the "its not a perfect number" to display. I need help with last part. It doesn't allow me to change it to else.

```
package editmess;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Editmess {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("\nPerfect Number Finder Program");

        System.out.print("\nEnter the start value: ");
        int starval = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter the end value:");
        int endval = scanner.nextInt();

        for (int n1 = starval; n1 < endval; n1++) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int n2 = 1; n2 < n1; n2++) {
                if (n1 % n2 == 0) {
                    sum = sum + n2;
                }
            }

            if (sum == n1) {
                System.out.println(n1 + " is a perfect number");
                if (sum != n1) {
                    System.out.println("There is no perfect number between " + starval + " and " + endval);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to learn how to properly indent and format code

Comment: "I need help with last part. It doesn't allow me to change it to else." What do you mean with this?

Comment: i need to change it to if - else                                                                                                             if (sum != n1) {
                    System.out.println("There is no perfect number between " + starval + " and " + endval);
                    break;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put an else statement inside and if statement unless there is another if statement there.

Here is the whole code. Also you weren't reading in all the numbers entered. The first for loop should be n1 <= endval; and not n1 < endval; so that it also checks the enval entered.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int counter = 0;

    System.out.println("\nPerfect Number Finder Program");

    System.out.print("\nEnter the start value: ");
    int starval = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter the end value:");
    int endval = scanner.nextInt();

    for (int n1 = starval; n1 <= endval; n1++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int n2 = 1; n2 < n1; n2++) {
            if (n1 % n2 == 0) {
                sum = sum + n2;
            }
        }

        if (sum == n1) {
            System.out.println(n1 + " is a perfect number");
             counter ++; //This will add one to the counter if this loop is enterd
            }
         if(n1 == endval){
            System.out.println("FINISHED!");
            break;
         }
    }
    //If the counter is 0 then it will display the message
    if(counter == 0){
        System.out.println("THERE IS NO PERFECT NUMBERS");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So i tried it but it keep that there is not number.                                                             Enter the start value: 1
Enter the end value:100
There is no perfect number between1 and 100